# How to move the uiview part of the screen from right to left using CATransition

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application.In that i want to move the uiview from right to left using below code.

```
-(void)centerAnimation1:(id)sender
{
theview=qstnview;
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
animation.delegate = self;
[animation setDuration:0.4];
[animation setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];

if(rhtolft)
{
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
}
else 
{
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
}
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
//[animation setanima]
[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];

[[theview layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
[qstnview removeFromSuperview];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    if(animate)
     {
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.delegate = self;
    [animation setDuration:0.4];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionMoveIn];
    if(rhtolft)
    {
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
        rhtolft=NO;
    }
    else 
    {
        [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    }
    //[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    //[animation setanima]

         [[theview layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];


         [self.view addSubview:qstnview];

}
 }
```

But this one is moving the view from right side last edge to left side.But i need to move within the frame size only.I dont need to start from right side edge.So please tell me how to do that one.

Comment: hey mate just see this link demo which display your output, just see.. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/iiviewdeckcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need to dive down to CA to do this kind of thing. It can be done using UIView animations. Here http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial is a good tutorial on UIView animations.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33f 
                  delay:0.0f 
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
             animations:^{
                 [theView setFrame:newFrame]; //set new frame for view where x =200;
             }
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 // do whatever post processing you want (such as resetting what is "current" and what is "next")
             }];
```

The screen from right to left using CATransition like this

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.3];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[theView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rightToLeftAnimation"];
```

Comment: I want to move the view within the size of the screen only.That is i don't need to move view from right edge to left edge.I need to move the view from x value 200 to x value 100.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for changing images with animation:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype=kCATransitionFromLeft;
[yourImageViewName.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```